# Syntax Error in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, syntax

I'm using this code:

```
 if (in_category('finance')) {
      include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/category1.php');
 } elseif (in_category('2')) {
      include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/category2.php');
 } else {
      include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/default.php');
 }
```

Everything work fine. When I have category with name finance, will use template from category1.php.

But now I would like to include a specific template file based from an option request like this:

```
 <?php  echo $up_options->category1; ?>
```

So I insert that option request code into the first code to be like this:

```
 if (in_category('finance')) {
      include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/$up_options->category1;');
 } elseif (in_category('2')) {
      include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single2.php');
 } else {
      include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/category1.php');
 }
```

I'm getting the following error with the above code:

```
 [function.include]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in.....
```

Really appreciate for any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$up_options is a variable, but you are using it as a string. Try doing it like this:

```
if (in_category('finance')) {
  include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $up_options->category1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ninja. Unfortunately your code not work, the same error still occur.

Answer (score 0):

Your include `'/$up_options->category1;'` will be parsed as a `string` as you are using single quotes. Try by changing it to double quotes "`/$up_options->category1;"`.

I don't think you need to add `;` at last, so this will be more appropriate

`"/$up_options->category1"`

Second option already suggested by @ninja -

`TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . $up_options->category1`

Comment: @AnabeleRosemary what is in `echo $up_options->category1;` ? and paste full error code

Comment: Its call for template with name: category1.php, and category2.php . Here the error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER in D:\0-SERVER\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\MARIO\category.php on line 31"

Comment: @AnabeleRosemary `var_dump()` $up_options->category1; and paste the result in your question as an edit...and let me know then ALSO your this time error seems to be different from the previous you mentioned in the post **Invalid argument....**